# Calculating Sums and Averages of inputted numbers, and sorting numbers in Eclipse

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, for-loop

The Problem: Write a program that reads in five whole numbers from the user. The program will calculate and output

the following statistics about the five numbers:

• `The sum of all of the positive numbers (greater than zero).`

• `The sum of all of the non-positive numbers (less than or equal to zero).`

• `The sum of all five numbers.`

• `The average of all of the positive numbers (greater than zero).`

• `The average of all of the non-positive numbers (less than or equal to zero).`

• `The average of all five numbers.`

Here is what I have for my code:

```
package assignment_09_20_2018;

import java.util.Scanner ; 

public class LAB_Assignment_09_20_2018 {

    public LAB_Assignment_09_20_2018() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int length; 

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        //opens scanner

        System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers: ") ;

        length = input.nextInt() ; 

        Int[] numbers = new Int[length]


    }
}
```

someone in my class said to use arrays and for loops but i have no idea how to, please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use array and for loop as shown in below code. I am using an int[] array to store the 5 numbers to be input by the user and populating that using a for loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException, ParseException {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers: ") ;
        int[] array = new int[5];
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
}
```

Now you can use a for-loop and cover all the cases given in the question.

**For example**: `The sum and average of all five numbers` can be calculated as shown below:

```
//sum of all 5 numbers

int sum=0;
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    sum += array[i];
}
System.out.println(sum); // Prints the sum of 5 numbers
int average = sum/array.length;
System.out.println(average); // Prints the average of 5 numbers
```

**EDIT:** Code for  `sum of positive numbers and negative numbers only`

```
int posSum=0;
int negSum=0;
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    if(array[i]>0){
        posSum += array[i];
    }else if(array[i]<0){
        negSum += array[i];
    }
}
System.out.println("Positive number only sum is "+posSum);
System.out.println("Negative number only sum is "+negSum);
```

Comment: How could I find the sum and average of just the positive and negative numbers? I am still slightly confused on the proper syntax for the if-else statement

Comment: @JVinitsky I have updated the answer for calculating the `sum of positive and negative numbers using one for loop`

Comment: Thank you!! This was very helpful

Comment: @JVinitsky if you found the answer helpful then please mark it as accepted by clicking on the check to the left of this answer under upvote/downvote button.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer, I'm a C# guy so my syntax may not be entirely right.**

---

Create a loop to accept numbers into an array.

```
Int [] numbers = new Int [5]{};

for (Int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter a number.");
    numbers[i] = Scanner(System.in);
}
```

Then use math on the array with a combination of if statements to determine < or > values.

```
for (Int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
   if ( numbers[i] < 0)
      {
         // do this math
      }
else if (numebers[I] > 0)
   {
     // do this math.
   }
}
```

and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously homework, so I'll just help with the Java code for reading in the numbers, then provide some pseudocode for the required calculations.

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int length = 5;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers: ") ;
    int[] numbers = new int[length];
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
      numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    // calculations go here
  }
```

Calculations would look something like this:

```
posSum = posCount = negSum = negCount = 0
for n in numbers
  if n > 0
    posSum = posSum + n
    posCount = posCount + 1
  else
    negSum = negSum + n
    negCount = negCount + 1
```

You now have the required positive and negative sums. The total sum is obviously these added. Given `posSum` and `posCount` you can calculate the average positive number (check for the case where `posCount` is 0). The same for average negative.

Finally, a question - do you need to keep track of `posCount` *and* `negCount`, or could you calculate one from the other once the loop is done?

Comment: Well in the example output it stated something along the lines like: Enter five whole numbers: -1 1 -2 2 -3

The sum of the 2 positive numbers: 3

The sum of the 3 non-positive numbers: -6

The sum of the 5 numbers: -3

The average of the 2 positive numbers: 1.50

The average of the 3 non-positive numbers: -2.00

The average of the 5 numbers: -0.60